# Stored procedure with EXECUTE AS cannot run xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2008, impersonation, xp-cmdshell

I have a sql server user, *proxyAccount*, which I configured as `xp_cmdshell_proxy_account`

In a stored procedure I use `xp_cmdshell`, and when I execute the stored procedure with this account, everything works fine.

However, if I add:

```
WITH EXECUTE AS 'proxyAccount'
```

to the stored procedure, I get the following error when I execute it:

> The xp_cmdshell proxy account information cannot be retrieved or is invalid. Verify that the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential exists and contains valid information.

What might be the problem? Why can't *proxyAccount* run `xp_cmdshell` when set to EXECUTE AS, but being able to run it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by the following steps:

1. Creating a new account that uses Windows Authentication (not using SQL Server Authentication)
2. Set this new account to xp_cmdshell proxy
3. Grant xp_cmdshell permission to the old *proxyAccount*